# What would entail hiding the price for some products on Amazon?

Tags: usability, website-design, forms, user-behavior, design-patterns

I've noticed that when I search on Amazon for a product, there usually will be some results where the price will not be visible until you click on the product and then again click on "See all buying options" button.



[image]

1. Is this not a bad user experience? I mean why would you need the user to make multiple clicks in order to see the product price?
2. Would this also not put a seller at a disadvantage? Surely, I wouldn't bother going into the product detail page if I can see the prices of other listings?

I've also noticed that whenever the price is hidden, they usually turn out to be exorbitant when compared to other listings (mostly 2x to 3x than the standard pricing). This makes me believe that it is for this reason that Amazon follows this "hiding of price" approach for such listings.

Comment: Since those exorbitant prices are from third-party scalpers, er, sellers, I would *guess* that maybe sometimes Amazon doesn't list the price because price or availability is very volatile (and therefore less friendly to cached search results).

Comment: Definitely a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

> **Why Don't We Show the Price?**
> Retailers like Amazon have the legal right to set their own prices independently, but some manufacturers place restrictions on how those prices may be communicated. Because our price on this item is lower than the manufacturer's "minimum advertised price," the manufacturer does not allow us to show you our price until you take further action, such as placing the item in your shopping cart, or in some cases, proceeding to the final checkout stage. The steps required depend on the details of the manufacturer's minimum advertised price policy. Taking these steps allows Amazon to show you our price consistent with our goal of always offering you the lowest possible prices on the widest selection of products.
> This won't require you to purchase the product. You can easily remove it from your cart if you decide not to buy it.
> We realize that this is an inconvenience and are regularly working to educate manufacturers on how their policies impact our customers. We welcome your comments and suggestions in our forum on this topic.

<sup>*Via [Amazon: Why don't we show the price?](https://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?ie=UTF8&docId=174014)*</sup>

Comment: While true, I don't think this applies to the specific case mentioned by the OP.

Comment: I think so too. Useful information nonetheless. Thanks.